# Access Class Library file path in Web project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, relative-path

I have a web project (e.g. MyWebProject) and a class library project (e.g. MyCLProject) in my MVC solution.

I wan't to access a file path in my web project of a file that exist in Class Library project. Is there any way of mapping the class library path from my web project?

Answer (score 0):

there is reference in your mvc project just right click and add reference then select browse and select the class library path and hit ok.